# PM2 ecosystem.config.js ignore_watch restarting

Tags: node.js, config, pm2

Running my app with `pm2 start index.js --watch` functions as expected. I would like to use the config to `ignore_watch`.

**ecosystem.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "appname",
    script : "./index.js",
    watch  : true,
    max_mamory_restart : "1G",
    ignore_watch : "\.bash(rc|_(history|logout)),\.(cache|config|gitignore|lesshst|local|npm|pm2|profile|sudo_as_admin_successful|vscode_server),.*swp,snap,.*config.js,package-lock.json,node_modules,jira,logs"
  }]
}
```

When I run `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`, my app runs, but constantly restarts with `Change detected on path .pm2/.......`

I thought that maybe I am not writing the `ignore_watch` correctly, so I tried

```
ignore_watch : [
    ".pm2",
    "\.bash(rc|_(history|logout))",
    "\.cache|config|gitignore|lesshst|local|npm|pm2|profile|sudo_as_admin_successful|vscode_server)",
    ".*swp",
    "snap",
    ".*config.js,package-lock.json,node_modules,jira,logs"
]
```

which then gives me constant restarts with `Change detected on path .vscode_server/.......`

I then tried the same thing by editing `ignore_watch` to:

```
ignore_watch : [
    ".vscode_server",
    ".pm2",
```

but this still restarts with with `Change detected on path .vscode_server/.......`

I don't understand how the ignore_watch is working, especially where the original `pm2 start index.js --watch` doesn't appear to watch these folders and its not constantly restarting.